# XSL Sum of nodes

Tags: xslt

I am trying to calculate the SUM of some nodes. A Learner will have 1 or more Learning Aims, and I need to know the total of the GLH node for the Learning Aims for the learner.

Here is some sample XML.

```
<Learner>
<LearnRefNumber>422</LearnRefNumber>        
<FamilyName>John</FamilyName>
<GivenNames>Smith</GivenNames>
<LearningDelivery>
    <LearnAimRef>zilsk14a</LearnAimRef>
    <AimType>4</AimType>
    <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
    <GLH>2775</GLH>
</LearningDelivery>
<LearningDelivery>
    <LearnAimRef>zilsk14b</LearnAimRef>
    <AimType>4</AimType>
    <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
    <GLH>2500</GLH>
</LearningDelivery>
</Learner>
```

Here is my XSL. The count of the Learning Aims works fine, but I am struggling to SUM up the GLH.

```
<xsl:for-each select="t:Learner">
<div class="learner">              
    <xsl:variable name="LearningAims" select="count(t:LearningDelivery)" />
    <xsl:variable name="LearnerGLH" select="sum(t:LearningDelivery/GLH)" />

    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Learner Ref</th>
          <th>Learning Aims</th>
          <th>Total GLH</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="t:LearnRefNumber" />
          </td>

          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$LearningAims" />
          </td>

          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$LearnerGLH" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Please help. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing `sum(t:LearningDelivery/GLH)`, but in the input XML the LearningDelivery and GLH elements are in the same namespace.  You want `sum(t:LearningDelivery/t:GLH)`.